# Does a Wi-Fi router record "handshakes" with devices that don't automatically connect?

Tags: wireless-networking

Does a Wi-Fi router record "handshakes" with devices that don't automatically connect? That is, devices that have not connected before, and are not authenticated on that network?

If so, how would one retrieve the MAC addresses of such devices?

Answer (score 0):

There's no requirement in any standard for 802.11 APs (Wi-Fi routers) to record anything at all. So there's no telling what one device or another might record.

If you're just looking for MAC addresses of wireless devices in range of your network, use an 802.11 monitor mode packet sniffer (such as Wireshark, with the right radio hardware) to watch for probe requests, authentication requests, and association requests.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly can happen.  I doubt that this is required for a standard "router" to perform its basic function, so there are probably many cases where this probably does not happen.  However, I have heard of something quite similar to this happening.

Apparently airports will sometimes have a sign that provides an estimated time, describing how long it is taking for people to get through security.  I read that this estimate was done by having a specialized device, acting like a "Wi-Fi access point".  Some people have phones that perform some sort of early part of the handshaking process, and the specialized device is able to detect the signal strengths and track a unique address (I would guess the MAC-48 address) to figure out how quickly the device is moving through the security checkpoint.

Even if many people don't have Wi-Fi auto-scanning enabled (which is probably a good idea, to save battery life), enough other people do have that enabled, that estimates can be provided.

That is just the one instance, of this actually happening, that I've heard of.  I suspect that many other organizations, interested in monitoring crowd movements, may be doing similar things.  I expect more and more organizations will be seeking to use such opportunities, in their efforts to try to take advantage of "big data" opportunities (capturing all kinds of data, and seeing how they can make it useful).